# operator precedence in C?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

```
int x=12;
int y=7;
int z=19;
int sum;

sum = ++x >= y * 2 || y % 2 && z++ % 2;
```

I am a little bit confused about the operator precedence?
what is the first condition the compiler will read in the above code?
Is it going to first evaluate `y % 2 && z++ % 2` since `&&` has precedence over `||` or is the compiler still going to go from left to right and short circuit if on the very left `++x >= y * 2` is true? i.e is the code going to be read in the following way by the compiler?

```
sum = (++x >= y * 2 || y % 2 )&& z++ % 2;
```

Comment: Whenever in doubt, you just add the `(` and `)` to get the order you need. You will never, ever have any practical use for code that is this complicated.

Comment: @BoPersson: Funny but I sit on the other side of the fence, and dogmatically too. Learning your precedence table doesn't take long and makes for much more readable code.

Comment: @BoPersson doesn't that fail the whole purpose of the code? btw, this is an exam question. I can't really put brackets myself to force the compiler to compile a chunk of code first.

Comment: @usr yes thats the point of the whole question, to learn about the precedence, I know the precedence table, perhaps you should re read my question.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Yes, it is good to know the order of `+` and `*`, but very much less useful when it is `&& z++ % 2`.

Comment: @BoPersson: Even so, it only takes a few hours to learn it. Stick the precedence table to the door of your downstairs toilet.

Comment: @Stannis - I argue that this is **only** useful for an exam. If you were to try this on my code review, you would get your final warning. Once more and you would be looking for a new job.  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson haha yes, I agree that this is a good way to learn the precedence table, but these questions can be really difficult sometimes.

Comment: @StannisBaratheon yes, difficult to understand, difficult to debug, and the reason why temporary, intermediate vars, extra lines and brackets were all invented.  Also, saves you getting fired or an 'F-' mark:)

Comment: @usr I wouldn't ask about the precedence table if I didn't know how it worked. If you read the question carefully, it can confuse the hell out of someone easily.

Comment: @zerkms Associativity only comes into play when there are two operators with the same precedence next to each other. It does not apply anywhere in this expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expression is grouped as

```
(++x >= (y * 2)) || ((y % 2) && (z++ % 2))
```

and this is assigned to `sum`. This is specified by the *grammar* of C.

Note also that the right hand side of `||` is **not** evaluated if the left hand side is `1`: which will mean that `z` is not incremented in that case.

1. For avoidance of doubt, `++x` is the *new* value of `x`, and `z++` is the *old* value of `z`.
2. Note also that because `||` is a *sequencing point*, the expression would be well defined even had you written `x++` on the right hand side, rather than `z++`.
3. Calling the result of this `sum` is an exercise in obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know that the right side of `||` is not evaluated if left side is true, but what confused me here really was whether the left side of `||` will even evaluate or not since `&&` had a higher precedence over `||`

Comment: @StannisBaratheon roughly precedence tells you the way parenthesis can be added and associativity the order of evaluation in multiple operator of same precedence's expression. Precedence tells you that `a || b && c || d` should be read as `a || (b&&c) || d`, and associativity tells you that the first thing to evaluate is `a || (b&&c)`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Associativity also only tells you how parentheses are added. Specifically it tells you whether `x $ y $ z` is equivalent to `x $ (y $ z)` (if `$` is a right-associative operator) or `(x $ y) $ z` (if it's left-associative). That still does not tell you whether the left or right operand is evaluated first.

Answer (score 5):

Order of evaluation has nothing to do with precedence (or associativity for that matter). The fact that `&&` has higher precedence than `||` tells you that `a || b && c` is equivalent to `a || (b && c)`. This does not tell you whether `a` or `b && c` get evaluated first.

In case of `||` and `&&` the standard specifies that the left operand is evaluated first (and the right operand is not evaluated at all if the left operand evaluated to true (in case of `||`) or false (in case of `&&`) respectively). So in `a || (b && c)`, we know that the order is `a`, `b`, then `c` (assuming all three end up being evaluated).

For most other operators, the standard does not specify the order of evaluation, so, for example, in `a + b * c`, we know that it's equivalent to `a + (b * c)`, but we don't know whether `a` is evaluated before `b * c` nor whether `b` is evaluated before `c`.

Answer (score 2):

**Operator precedence specifies how an expression is *parsed*, not how it is evaluated**. Although related, evaluation order is something different! It is either specified by the specific operator, or it is unspecified.

Operator precedence dictates that the expression is equivalent to:

```
sum = ( ((++x) >= (y * 2)) || ((y % 2) && ((z++) % 2)) );
```

as operators have the following precedence order:

```
++ (postfix)
++ (prefix)
* % (same precedence)
>=
&&
||
```

If you think `sum = ( ((++x) >= (y * 2)) || ((y % 2) && ((z++) % 2)) );` is an unreadable mess, you are correct. It is however just as bad as the original expression. Never write multiple operators on a single line like this if you can avoid it.

That's as far as we go with operator precedence. it merely "glues" specific operators together with operands. It does not dictate the order of evaluation.

Think of it as in math: in a mathematical expression `(1 + 1 + 1 * 2 + 2 + 2)`, the operator precedence of math guarantees that `1` and `2` from the `1 * 2` belong together, but it doesn't tell you in which order you should solve the equation. You can start solving it by calculating `1 + 1` first, or `1 * 2` or `2 + 2`.

In the expression `sum = ++x >= y * 2 || y % 2 && z++ % 2`, only the `||` and `&&` have specified *order of evaluation*. These two operators in particular are sometimes informally referred to as having "short-circuiting" evaluation.

For the rest of the operators, the order of evaluation is *unspecified*, meaning we can't know anything about it or rely on it. The compiler doesn't even need to be consistent from expression to expression - the reason why is to allow compilers to produce the fastest possible code when parsing their expression trees.

The only thing we *can* know is that the sub expressions `++x`, `y * 2` and `[result of ++x] >= [result of y * 2]` *will* get evaluated before the right side of the `||`.

And in turn, if the right side of `||` does get evaluated, then `y % 2` will get evaluated before the rest of the sub expressions, because `&&` does guarantee the order of evaluation of its operands.